# PHP - Display image in LONGBLOB data for iPhone app

Tags: php, ios, mysql, image, blob

I am trying to stock images in my SQL base (I have them as a file too, I just want to use the MySQL database even though I know it consumes more memory...I have to try something). Anyways, I have them in a LONGBLOB column in my database, around 80MB of pictures in total.
Via an API Rest, I want to get that data, display it in JSON and get it in my iPhone app to be able to display the images in my app.
I am currently trying to display all that data on one page but I keep on getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 112720582 bytes) in /home/hosted/..... on line 47

Which is obviously quite normal because of how much memory it uses.
How else could I do this? I have to pass the data to my iPhone app, but how?